# In a binary circular array of length n,find if it can be partitioned such that most groups of adjacent elements of size m have more 1s than 0s

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example,if array is
001101100
there exists a partition
011 011 000
where maximum groups have more 1s than 0s.
However,in
100110100
there isnt.
I have tried brute force approach which takes O(n^3) time. Please suggest a more efficient approach,as that is not working.

Comment: Must all partitioned partitions have same number of elements? Are you allowed to have for e.g: 5 elements & 4 elements for a size 9 array?

Comment: yes,all partitions have same number of elements.also,n and m are odd.

Comment: do I get that right: `n` and `m` are given, `n = k * m` where all three numbers are odd. But then there are only `m` different partitions to test!? Each partition takes `O(n)` to check makes `O(n * m)` all together!?

Comment: Yes,n=k*m.So,you have to check k partitions,each of size m.Also,it is a circular array.Checking one set of partitions takes O(n*m) time.And there can be 'm' such unique set of partitions. That makes it O(n^3)(By n^3,I mean it has cubic complexity,not "n^3" literally).

Answer (score 0):

There's an O(n)-time algorithm that reuses the group sums. I'm assuming that "most" means majority instead of maximization, but the change isn't hard.

```
def circular(array, m):
    n = len(array)
    assert n % 2 == 1
    assert m % 2 == 1
    assert n % m == 0
    groupsums = [sum(array[j * m:(j + 1) * m]) for j in range(n // m)]
    for i in range(m):
        if sum(groupsum > m // 2 for groupsum in groupsums) > (n // m) // 2:
            return [[array[(j * m + k) % n] for k in range(i, i + m)]
                    for j in range(n // m)]
        for j in range(n // m):
            groupsums[j] -= array[(j * m + i) % n]
            groupsums[j] += array[((j + 1) * m + i) % n]


print(circular([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 3))
print(circular([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 3))
print(circular([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 3))
```

Comment: can you explain it please?

Comment: @usr1011 Not a lot to explain. Your brute force solution replaces the second for loop with code that recomputes the group sums from scratch. Instead, we update each group sum by subtracting its leftmost element and adding the next element to the right.